# Vagrant Omnibus Plugin Not Working on My Windows 7 PC

Tags: vagrant, chef-solo

I want to spin up a Fedora-20 VM using Vagrant and Chef on my Windows 7 PC and provision it as a LAMP server. I have Vagrant 1.6.5. and the vagrant-omnibus plugin (1.4.1) is installed.

My Vagrantfile includes the "config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest" statement, but after running "vagrant up", expected provisioning does not occur.  Instead,

```
==> default: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
The chef binary (either `chef-solo` or `chef-client`) was not found on
the VM and is required for chef provisioning. Please verify that chef
is installed and that the binary is available on the PATH.
```

It appears that the omnibus plugin did not install Chef on the VM. What else do I need to do to get this working on my PC?

This is my Vagrant file:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "chef/fedora-20"
  config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 4567
  config.vm.synced_folder "shared-files", "/var/www"
  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = "chef-recipes/cookbooks"
    chef.roles_path = "chef-recipes/roles"
    chef.add_role "lamp_stack"
  end
end
```

and here is STDOUT:

```
C:\Users\wbj\f20>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'chef/fedora-20'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'chef/fedora-20' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: f20_default_1413836754304_46591
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 => 4567 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /var/www => C:/Users/wbj/f20/shared-files
    default: /vagrant => C:/Users/wbj/f20
    default: /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-2/roles => C:/Users/wbj/f20/chef-recipes/roles
    default: /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks => C:/Users/wbj/f20/chef-recipes/cookbooks
==> default: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
The chef binary (either `chef-solo` or `chef-client`) was not found on
the VM and is required for chef provisioning. Please verify that chef
is installed and that the binary is available on the PATH.
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you get the debug logs with something like `vagrant up --debug >vagrant.log 2>&1` and gist/pastebin it?

Comment: You could also try to use a specific version: `config.omnibus.chef_version = "11.16.4"`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact problem. The solution was to downgrade to Vagrant 1.6.2 until Vagrant version 1.7.1 was released. Both versions fixed the problem for me.